# onclick event instead of clicking <a href /> in jquery and fancy box to open iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I have several divs that are inside "a href" like:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe popup" href="iframe_1.html" height="35px" width="98%" > 
    <section class="one">
        <div class="twoe over"  data-direction="right" af="1">      
          <div class="front" >
            <img src="1.jpg" width ="100%;" height ="100%;" alt="">
          </div>         
          <div class="back" style="background-color:#99ca3c;">
                <h1></h1><br/><br/><br/>
                <h2>132
                </h2>
                <h3></h3>               
          </div>         
        </div>
    </section>
     </a>


 <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe popup" href="iframe_2.html" height="35px" width="98%" > 
    <section class="one">
        <div class="twoe over"  data-direction="right" af="2">      
          <div class="front" >
            <img src="2.jpg" width ="100%;" height ="100%;" alt="">
          </div>         
          <div class="back" style="background-color:#99ca3c;">
                <h1></h1><br/><br/><br/>
                <h2>222
                </h2>
                <h3></h3>               
          </div>         
        </div>
    </section>
     </a>
```

now I am using fancy box, so each time a div is clicked I call a frame with class popup:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
    $("a.popup").fancybox({
            /*'width'             : '100%',
            'height'            : '100%',*/
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe'
    });
```

Now the problem is, that I need to click twice instead of once the div and do not know why, so one solution I think can solve this issue is to add an onclick event insidediv and call respective iframe, but I do not know how to do that.

Couls you please help with this issue?

Comment: You can refresh the page after closing fancybox each time to prevent this

Comment: so I tried `$("a.popup").fancybox({
            /*'width'             : '100%',
            'height'            : '100%',*/
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe',
   'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
            'onClosed'          : function() {
                                  parent.location.reload(true);
                                  }
   
    });`  but still need to click twice the "a href"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("a.popup").fancybox({
 'onClosed' : function() { 
      location.reload(true); } 
});
```

you need to reload the page rether than giving it as parent page like

```
parent.location.reload(true);
```

and the diff between onClosed and inCleanup is like this

"**onCleanup**" is the earlier call even though the popup is not closed completly,but "**onClosed**" is when the popup is completly closed...in detail if you click on close button of popup it first fires "**onCleanup**" and starts closing and after closing completely it will fire "**onClosed**"

Comment: could you please explain why is it necessary to reload the parant page? , also what is the diference between using `'onClosed' : function() { 
      location.reload(true); } `  and `onCleanup   : function() {
                return window.location.reload();
            }` ?